# Combine cell strings when condition is matched, and remove duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, substring, powerquery

I'm over my head here, but hoping someone can help.

Would like C3 to display all the strings from C15 to C60 for rows where column E matches B3, and remove duplicates / only display uniques.

Also, I would like D3 to display the strings from D15 to D60 as the prior question, however the cells potentially contain comma separated values - is there a way I can do as above but treat the comma separated values as separate strings?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV6oA.png) and [spreadsheet to download](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a43b98cf7bd0513a8206b9553df8e22b20200322205222/35f3ba04fee0785b604a5064ca5e115f20200322205359/a5ad31).

Thanks in advance for anyone taking a look.

Joe

Comment: Yes there is. Depending on your version of Excel, you might be able to do this using formulas; you can certainly do it using `VBA` or `Power Query`

Answer (score 0):

excel have a function to remove duplicate data, did you try it?

just copy your origin data then remove duplicate.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Retrieve Possibly Separated Unique Data

**Usage:**

Copy the code into a standard module and in Excel use the following formulas:

in Cell C3  `=CritJoe(C$15:C$60,$E$15:$E$60,$B3)`

in Cell D3  `=CritJoe(D$15:D$60,$E$15:$E$60,$B3,",")`

**The Code**

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:  Retrieves unique ((comma) separated) (ResultSeparator) data
'           determined by a criteria (Criteria) in a specified column
'           (CriteriaRange) from another specified column (SourceRange)
'           possibly containing (comma) separated (StringSeparator) strings.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function CritJoe(SourceRange As Range, CriteriaRange As Range, _
  Criteria As String, Optional StringSeparator As String = "", _
  Optional ResultSeparator As String = ", ") As String

    Dim vntS            ' Source Array (1-based, 2-dimensional)
    Dim vntC            ' Criteria Array (1-based, 2-dimensional)
    Dim vntSS           ' Source String Array (0-based, 1-dimensional)
    Dim vntR            ' Resulting Array (0-based, 1-dimensional)
    Dim i As Long       ' Source & Criteria Array Elements Counter
    Dim j As Long       ' Resulting Array Elements Counter
    Dim k As Long       ' Source String Array Elements Counter
    Dim UB As Long      ' Current Resulting Array's Upper Bound
    Dim strS As String  ' Current Source String
    Dim strR As String  ' Resulting String

    ' Check if SourceRange and CriteriaRange have the same number of rows and
    ' have the same first row number.
    If SourceRange.Rows.Count <> CriteriaRange.Rows.Count Or _
      SourceRange.Rows(1).Row <> CriteriaRange.Rows(1).Row Then GoTo RowsError
    ' Note:  The relevant data has to be in the first column of each range
    ' if (accidentally) more columns have been selected.

    ' Copy first column of the Ranges to Arrays.
    vntS = SourceRange.Cells(1).Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count)
    vntC = CriteriaRange.Cells(1).Resize(CriteriaRange.Rows.Count)

    ' Write relevant data to Resulting Array.
    For i = 1 To UBound(vntS)
        ' To avoid "Case/Space issues", "parts" of the following can be used:
        ' If Upper(Trim(vntC(i, 1))) = Upper(Trim(Criteria)) Then
        ' ... instead of the following line:
        If vntC(i, 1) = Criteria Then
            strS = vntS(i, 1)
            If StringSeparator <> "" Then
                ' Write Resulting String to Resulting Array using
                ' StringSeparator.
                GoSub SplitString
            Else
                ' Write Resulting String to Resulting Array without
                ' using StringSeparator.
                GoSub StringToArray
            End If
        End If
    Next

    ' Write relevant data from Resulting Array to Resulting String.
    If IsArray(vntR) Then
        strR = vntR(0)
        If UBound(vntR) > 0 Then
            For j = 1 To UBound(vntR)
                strR = strR & ResultSeparator & vntR(j)
            Next
        End If
    End If

    CritJoe = strR

Exit Function

' Write Resulting String to Resulting Array using StringSeparator.
SplitString:
    vntSS = Split(strS, StringSeparator)
    For k = 0 To UBound(vntSS)
        strS = Trim(vntSS(k))
        GoSub StringToArray
    Next
    Return

' Write Resulting String to Resulting Array.
StringToArray:
    If IsArray(vntR) Then
        ' Handle all except the first element in Resulting Array.
        UB = UBound(vntR)
        For j = 0 To UB
            If vntR(j) = strS Then Exit For
        Next
        If j = UB + 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve vntR(j): vntR(j) = strS
        End If
    Else
        ' Handle only first element in Resulting Array.
        ReDim vntR(0): vntR(0) = strS
    End If
    Return

RowsError:
    CritJoe = "Rows Error!"

End Function
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote, it's relatively simple with Power Query, available in Excel 2010+.  It takes longer to type out the steps then to create it :-).

All can be done from the UI

- Remove the `Scene` and `Video` Columns
- Split the `Cast` column by the `comma` delimiter
- Select the `Location` and `Cast` columns and `Transform/Trim` to eliminate unwanted spaces
- Select all three columns and `Remove Rows/Duplicates`
- `Group By` `Recording Block` `Operation:= All Rows`

  - Name the Column `Grouped`

[image]

- Add Custom Column for the Locations:  Formula =

  `List.Distinct(Table.Column([Grouped],"Location"))`

  - note the new column name in the dialog box

[image]

- Add another Custom Column for the Cast:  Formula =

  `List.Distinct(Table.Column([Grouped],"Cast"))`

[image]

- Select the double-headed arrow at the top of the new columns

  - `Extract Values` from the drop down and select a delimiter -- I used the `Custom -->` <kbd>comma</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd>
- Close and Load to wherever you want on the worksheet.

[image]

Of note, this workbook can be saved as an `xlsx` file.

For interest, here is the M-Code generated.

#### M Code

```
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Video", Int64.Type}, {"Scene", Int64.Type}, {"Location", type text}, {"Cast", type text}, {"Recording Block", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Video", "Scene"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {{"Cast", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Cast"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Cast", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Cast", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Location", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Trimmed Text"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Recording Block"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Location=text, Cast=text, Recording Block=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Locations", each List.Distinct(Table.Column([Grouped],"Location"))),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Cast", each List.Distinct(Table.Column([Grouped],"Cast"))),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Cast", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text}),
    #"Extracted Values1" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Extracted Values", {"Locations", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ", "), type text})
in
    #"Extracted Values1"
```